# Create a loop until all cells have been used by script

Tags: vba, excel

I don't really know how to program but I have compiled a few scripts to achieve nearly what I want, but I have failed at the last step.

The script opens a .txt file from a file directory in, cell B2, sheet 2, and copies its contents into excel (as well as a notepad which I don't care about).

However, I have 120 file directories I want to do this for. At the moment my script just takes the directory from cell B2, I have the rest of the 119 directories below it in the B column, I run the script and delete the row and repeat, which is a bit painstaking.

I would just like the script to run through all 120 files in the B column automatically. Any help appreciated!

```
    Option Explicit

Sub ReadTxtFile()
    Dim start As Date
    start = Now

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim oFS As Object

   Dim filePath As String


    '''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path

    filePath = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
 MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    Dim arr(100000) As String
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    If oFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then
        On Error GoTo Err

        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
        Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
            arr(i) = oFS.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        oFS.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If

   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(1, arr(i), "Transmission", vbTextCompare) Then

        'Declare variables for the new output file
        Dim sOutputFileNameAndPath As String
        Dim FN As Integer
        sOutputFileNameAndPath = "C:\Users\nfraser\Documents\test\second.txt"
        FN = FreeFile

        'Open new output file
        Open sOutputFileNameAndPath For Output As #FN


        'While 'end of report' has not been found,
        'keep looping to print out contents starting from 'report'
        Do While InStr(1, arr(i), "Ancillary", vbTextCompare) = 0

            Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
            Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
            Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

            'Print into new output file
            Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

            'increment count
            i = i + 1

        Loop

        'Print out the 'end of report' line as well
        Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
        Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

        'Print 'end of report' line into new output file as well
        Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

        'close the new output file
        Close #FN

        'exit the 'For..Next' structure since 'end of report' has been found
        Exit For


    End If

Next

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", start, Now)

Exit Sub



Err:
    MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    oFS.Close
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. So you basically want to`Loop` through the cells in Column B from Row 2 to the end of Column B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick action, Try this:

Change this line:

> `filePath = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value`

Into a loop

```
Dim v As Variant, filepath As String
For Each v In Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    filepath = v.Value
    debug.Print filePath
   .... ' remainder of your code
```

.. then go to the `Next` line and write another `Next` line after it.

Comment: Nice one @A.S.H ! I've never heard of `xlCellTypeConstants` until now... after a quick google search, I came across an article on ozgrid.com that explains the special cells method: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm   ... learn something new every day!

Comment: @AustinD yeah, we all do! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `for... each` loop, looping through all cells in your current selection. Here's the pattern:

```
Dim cCell as Range
For Each cCell in Selection
    'do stuff
Next cCell
```

Now, since you change selections throughout your code, you have to store the selection at the onset into another variable, e.g. `originalSelection` and then loop through the cells in `originalSelection`. Otherwise, your selection will change during execution.

Adapting it to your code, we end up with the following... Please note: I broke your code into two methods---`ReadTxtFiles` and `copyTo`; the `ReadTxtFile()` sub was getting way too long.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadTxtFiles()
    Dim start As Date
    start = Now

    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim inputFilePath As String
    Dim outputFilePath As String
    Dim outputDirectory As String
    outputDirectory = "C:\Users\nfraser\Documents\test\"

    '''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
    Dim originalSelection As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set originalSelection = Selection

    For Each cCell In originalSelection
        inputFilePath = cCell.Value
        outputFilePath = outputDirectory & i & ".txt"
        copyTo inputFilePath, outputFilePath
    Next cCell

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", start, Now)

End Sub


Sub copyTo(inputPath As String, outputPath As String)
    Dim arr(100000) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'late binding
    Dim oFS As Object
    i = 0

    If oFSO.FileExists(inputPath) Then
        On Error GoTo Err 'ensure oFS gets closed

        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(inputPath)

        'read file contents into array
        Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
            arr(i) = oFS.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'close
        oFS.Close
    Else 'file didn't exist
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        If InStr(1, arr(i), "Transmission", vbTextCompare) Then

            'Declare variables for the new output file
            Dim FN As Integer
            FN = FreeFile

            'Open new output file
            Open outputPath For Output As #FN

            'While 'end of report' has not been found,
            'keep looping to print out contents starting from 'report'
            Do While InStr(1, arr(i), "Ancillary", vbTextCompare) = 0

                Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
                Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
                Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

                'Print into new output file
                Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

                'increment count
                i = i + 1

            Loop

            'Print out the 'end of report' line as well
            Debug.Print i + 1, arr(i)
            Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = i + 1
            Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = arr(i)

            'Print 'end of report' line into new output file as well
            Print #FN, i + 1 & " " & arr(i)

            'close the new output file
            Close #FN

            'exit the 'For..Next' structure since 'end of report' has been found
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    oFS.Close
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```